# is it possible to do in ssrs report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

```
Name age sons 

ram   22   5    (i want a drop down menu to enter age and number of sons in ssrs end user need to select)
kri   26   3
Total      8
```

is it possible to create in ssrs report

Answer (score 1):

SSRS is NOT meant for users to input forms, it is meant for reporting out not input in.  You may be better served with ASP.NET or something similar.  SSRS is meant for reporting only as one direction from a database, not to it.  It is not set up to be an input method for data entry.  It is very limited in scope with event controls and even if you could manage to do some updates to a database it would be very clunky and cumbersome to do.  However ASP.NET and other technologies have predefined forms built around this very thing.  They take a little bit longer to set up though.